# How to stop 'noreturn' functions disabling '-Wreturn-type' warning with GCC?

Tags: gcc, abort, noreturn

When using a macro that might expand to a function with a `noreturn` attribute, is there a way to stop it from suppressing `-Wreturn-type`?

Simple example:

```c
/* Defined in a separate header. */
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define MY_ASSERT_MACRO(test) ((void)((test) ? 0 : abort()))
#else
#  define MY_ASSERT_MACRO(test) ((void)(0 ? 0 : (test)))
#endif

/* C source file. */
int function(enum MyEnum foo)
{
  switch (foo) {
     case A: return 1;
     case B: return 1;
  }
  MY_ASSERT_MACRO(0);

  /* <-- Missing return! This should always warn! */
}
```

The problem with this is in release builds this gives a `-Wreturn-type` warning, and in debug builds it gives no warning at all, since abort has a `noreturn` attrubute.

I would like to get the warning in both cases so developers using debug builds don't break release builds.

Is there a (clean*) way to stop the abort function from disabling the `-Wreturn-type` warning?

---

Not very clean ways:

- Call abort with a cast to remove the `noreturn` attribute:
  `((void (*)(void))(*(((void **)abort))))()`
- Compare two things which could theoretically be the same:
  `(((const void *)(abort) != (const void *)(stderr)) ? abort() : 0)`

Comment: What about simply writing your own `my_abort()` function that just calls `abort()` and isn't declared `noreturn`, and having your macro call it instead?

Comment: The issue with using a real function is it can complicate linking across a large code-base.

Comment: You can define it in the header and make it `static` so every module gets a copy.  If the compiler starts to notice that it calls `abort()` and therefore can't return, mark it `__attribute__((noipa))`.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way is to simply disable noreturn attribute on `abort` by compiling with `-D__noreturn__= -fno-builtin-abort`. You could also use a custom wrapper:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <signal.h>
void myabort() {
    raise(SIGABRT);
}

#define abort() myabort()
```

and compile with `-include myabort.h`.

But I suggest not to do that and instead do release builds under `-Wall -Werror` in your CI and/or precommit hooks. Release builds can emit useful warnings for many reasons e.g. because `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` static checks are enabled or some variables that were used in `assert`s become unused. Thus working around `abort` would not solve the problem of debug/release inconsistency.

Comment: Isn't `-D__noreturn__=` technically Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hm, why? `__noreturn__` and `__attribute__` aren't even part of C standard.

Comment: Because anything starting with two underscores is reserved, and defining anything reserved is UB.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I think you are right but as I said I'm against the idea of disabling `abort` anyway. Proposed solutions are hacks anyway and hacks are bad anyway, with or without UB.